# CouchDb bulk rename

Tags: couchdb, bulk

For example I have posts with tag names, and I decided to rename one of the tags. Bulk Updating when I should know revision is not really suitable. Better if this could be as something integrated.

Comment: Can I clarify the question?  You have a bunch of documents in your database that look like this:
{
   ...,
   someField: 'some value',
   ...
}

And you want to change "someField" on all the documents to be "newFieldName" without losing the values.  Is that what you're asking?

Comment: Tags probably are an array, [CouchDB, Redis]. I want to rename all "CouchDB" tags to "couch-db", for example.

Answer (score 1):

Check out [Costco](http://harthur.github.com/costco/), which provides a simple interface that lets you write a little function that gets applied to all your documents to modify them.

You would write a simple function like:

```
function (doc) {
  // ignore documents without tags
  if (!doc.tags) return doc;

  for (var i = 0, len = doc.tags.length; i < len; i += 1) {
    // convert tag misspelled "couch-db" to real name "CouchDB"
    if (doc.tags[i] === "couch-db") doc.tags[i] = "CouchDB";
  }
  return doc;
}
```